# How to do mapping for LIST of object in spring mvc framework

Tags: spring-mvc

I have following **POJO class** as an input -

```
public class Input implements java.io.Serializable {

    private String id;
    private List<Inputbenefit> Inputbenefits;
    //and getter and setter method 
}
```

Now In the **controller** i have initbinder -

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(Object target,WebDataBinder binder) {  
    binder.registerCustomEditor(ArrayList.class, new CustomCollectionEditor(ArrayList.class) {   
        @Override  
        protected Object convertElement(Object element) {
            Input  input= new Input ();     
            if (element != null) {
                ArrayList<Inputbenefit> id = (ArrayList<Inputbenefit>) element;
                input.setInputbenefits(id);
            }
        return input;
    } 
});
```

Post method signature in controller is -

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addDependentOutput.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String OutputForm(@ModelAttribute("Input") Input input, BindingResult result, Model model)
```

**In JSP** - I have 5 fixed text boxes to take value for Input class -

```
<spring:bind path="inputbenefits.benefitId">                
    <form:input path="${status.expression}" size="10" value="Manisha"/>
</spring:bind>
```

I am not getting the values from html form to OutputForm i.e. not able to read the value of `inputbenefits.benefitId` filed in controller post method OutputForm.

In short - my List object values are not getting passed to controller method.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Please post your question in proper format especially the code. Also, you have not mentioned what error you are getting. :(

Comment: Hi Subhkriti, I edited my post. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't return host object from converElement method, you should return your collection object instead

```
        @Override  
        protected Object convertElement(Object element) {
            int benefitId = Integer.parseInt(element.toString());
            return benefitService.getById(benefitId);
        }
```

**UPDATE**

I suppose you trying to bind collection on benefits to your Input object and you have a form to create new Input and select control to select desired benefits. Right? If true, you need something like this

Use form spring tags

```
        <form:select path="inputBenefits" items="${benefits}" 
         multiple="multiple" size="5" itemLabel="additionalAmt" itemValue="benefitId"/>
        <form:errors path="inputBenefits"/>
```

where ${benefits} collection of available benefits that you path to the page

In your controller you need

```
@InitBinder
    public void initBinder(ServletRequestDataBinder binder) {
     binder.registerCustomEditor(List.class, "inputBenefits", new CustomCollectionEditor(List.class) {

            protected Object convertElement(Object element) {
                if (element != null) {
                    Integer benefitId = Integer.parseInt(element.toString());
                    Benefit benefit = benefitService.getById(benefitId); // something that able to get benefit object
                    return benefit;

                }
                return null;
            }

        });

    }
```

This way method convertElement will be called for every value selected on page select control. After that collection of benefits will be pushed to command form object (Input i suppose)

simple example here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_mvc_form_handling_example.htm

Comment: Hi Georgy, I think we are close enough. I have following fields as a part of Inputbenefit.class {                                                                      private java.lang.String wqBtId;
private java.lang.String benefitId;
private double additionalAmt;
private boolean elected;
  }
how can i write  convertElement(Object element) method for this?